# ffmpeg socks4 proxy parameter with rtmp

Tags: proxy, ffmpeg, rtmp, socks

I am unable to capture some livestreams because of the proxy issues. So in rtmpdump i can use:

```
rtmpdump -v -r rtmp://a_rtmp_address -p http://a_http_address -S 85.185.244.101:1080 -B 10 -o aaa.flv
```

But I need to use ffmpeg or avconv. But I can not find a parameter corresponds to that -S 85.185.244.101:1080 parameter.

Can anyone please give me an ffmpeg command corresponding to this rtmpdump command.

Answer (score 1):

You should place socks option in quotes with rtmp:// address.
Options must be in the form KEY=VALUE after rtmp://. Like this:

```
ffmpeg ... -f flv "rtmp://a_rtmp_address socks=85.185.244.101:1080"
```