# Is it possible to download live videos?

Tags: flash, http, video-streaming

I've been searching these kinds of stuff for a while, and now get fiddler working. But I can only get a bunch of HTTP packets that seems to be useless.

[image]

Is there any way to reconstruct this live stream to a video file?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is [RTMPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol#HTTP_tunneling_.28RTMPT.29) which is `RTMP` tunneled via `HTTP`.

[ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) supports the protocol and can record the live stream in a wide variety of formats:

`ffmpeg -re -i rtmpt://<server_address>/<stream_name> -c copy output.flv`

You can also use [RTMPDump](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/).

Comment: how can I get the `server_address` and `stream_name`?

Comment: @amos Search the source of the webpage for `rtmp://` or `rtmpt://`. The URLs can also be in another file such as a `smil` for some players.

Comment: thanks. I almost got it working. However I need to use a sock5 proxy to watch this live flash. Does `ffmpeg` support downloading via a socks proxy?

Comment: @amos `ffmpeg` uses [librtmp](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html) and you can apparently set its options using space separated key=value pairs (quotes must be included): `-i "rtmp://.... socks=..."`. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22098045/ffmpeg-socks4-proxy-parameter-with-rtmp It's socks4 though...

Comment: Almost there now. I'm getting `RTMP_Connect0, SOCKS negotiation failed.`. I'm sure my socks proxy is pretty healthy. All system's traffic go through it.

Comment: @amos The lib supports only SOCKS4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92756/discussion-between-amos-and-aergistal).